# Need to load in inventory in JAVA , input from a .dat or .txt file

Tags: java

Alright guys, I have been working on this for a long time, I have a movie inventory

```
    Iroman 3
    Momento 2
    LifeofPi 2
    Superman 2
    The Crazies 1
```

get an exception: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 49726F6E  ( MEANS Iron first part of my inputfile.)

I understand why it wont let me load in:
An ObjectInputStream deserializes primitive data and objects previously written using an ObjectOutputStream. "inventory.dat is probably not a file of serialized objects previously written using an ObjectOutputStream. You probably want to use InputStreamReader instead

I tried using InputStreamreader, but obviously the object i will work with is not going to work with this type of input method

-------The inventory is a soretled list of data items(the ADT sorted list implemented as a linked list of data items), sorted by the title that each item represents.

-------- Each inventory item contains a title, a have value, a want value , and a list of customers(the waiting list)

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //
    //  Loading from the inventory.dat
    //
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new 
                            FileInputStream("inventory.dat");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object o = ois.readObject();
        inventory = (SortedList)o;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        inventory = new SortedList();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You state:

> I tried using InputStreamreader, but obviously the object i will work with is not going to work with this type of input method

No, there is nothing obvious about your problem that suggests that it won't work with this type of input method. Don't assume anything until your code is working, and don't assume that anything that you think is obvious is obvious to us. The only thing that I see that is obvious is that if your file holds text data, you should not use an ObjectInputStream as this is for serialized data, not text, and instead you should use InputStreamReader wrapped by a BufferedReader. Either that or use a Scanner with your File.

You read in the data, split the data, and then create your inventory object by using its constructor for each line of data read in.

Pseudocode:

```
Create File from your file path String
Create Scanner object, fileScanner with the File
while the fileScanner has a nextLine to read
  String line gets fileScanner's nextLine.
  Create a line Scanner object, lineScanner, with line of text.
  name String gets lineScanner's next token
  value int gets lineScanner's next int.
  close lineScanner
  Create your object of interest with the name and value values
  put it in your collection
end while loop
close fileScanner
```

Comment: Streamreader isn't a java class, would you be able to show me how via brief example or implementation?

Comment: @johnsmith: see edit. Regarding implementation first let's see your attempt to use it.

Comment: @johnsmith: no, post code as an edit to your question, and test your code before posting it. Then post any errors. You'll see that you should never do a cast like that.

Comment: @johnsmith You're still trying to use your `ObjectInputStream`. Delete it, entirely, and create a `BufferedReader` with the ISR as the parameter.

Comment: Thank you Hover for the psuedocode, the object i am trying to utilize is a Linkedlist, to store the title and int value.

Comment: @johnsmith: then by all means, go for it.

Comment: If the implementation is easier, can you expand on your answer @Vulcan. not sure what you mean by putting ISR(Inputsteamreader) as parameter

Comment: @johnsmith I would, but it's more time-efficient for both of us if you simply look up a `BufferedReader` tutorial on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe at the last vasing object to file.You foget to call flush() and close your stream.
That will cause losing data